# my server is giving me a timeout message on a for loop

Tags: php

I have a form in page1.php that has some checkboxes in it:

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="F10">
<input type="checkbox" name="W10">
<input type="checkbox" name="F20">
<input type="checkbox" name="W20">
<input type="checkbox" name="F30">
<input type="checkbox" name="W30">
<input type="checkbox" name="F11">
<input type="checkbox" name="W11">
<input type="checkbox" name="F21">
<input type="checkbox" name="W21">
<input type="checkbox" name="F31">
<input type="checkbox" name="W31">
<input type="checkbox" name="F12">
<input type="checkbox" name="W12">
<input type="checkbox" name="F22">
<input type="checkbox" name="W22">
<input type="checkbox" name="F32">
<input type="checkbox" name="W32">
</form>
```

page2.php

```
<?php 
$g=0;
$coursesD= array();
    for($f=1;$f++;$f<4){
        for($l=0;$l++;$l<3){
            if(isset($_POST["F".$f.$l])){
                $coursesD[$g]=$_POST["F".$f.$l];
                $g++;
            }
            if(isset($_POST["W".$f.$l])){
                $coursesD[$g]=$_POST["W".$f.$l];
                $g++;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

But after I submit the form it start loading and then it displays this message:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\4\page2.php on line 5

Please Help me

Comment: It's ICE: Initialization, Check, Execute. (so: `for($f=1;$f++;$f<4){` => `for($f=1;$f<4;$f++){`. Right now for instance: `$f++` is always true if it doesn't become 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you `for` loops are in the wrong order

its supposed to be

```
for(starting condition;loop condition;after each loop){
```

yours have the last 2 in the wrong order so f++ is aways true, therefore will loop forever (and cause a timeout)